# query values which doesn't exists in other collection mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Having two collections (orders, products)

I need to generate a list of the products in the orders collection which doesn't exist on the products collection so I can use those results in python to get the missing info from an API

this is what I need :

collection orders example document:

```js
  {
    order_id: 1,
    product_id: "PROD001",
  },
  {
    order_id: 2,
    product_id: "PROD002",
  },
  {
    order_id: 3,
    product_id: "PROD002",
  },
  {
    order_id: 4,
    product_id: "PROD003",
  }
```

collection products example document:

```js
  {
    product_id: "PROD001",
    name: "product number 01",
  },
  {
    product_id: "PROD002",
    name: "product number 02",
  }
```

the list I need to generate in python

```
notfound=["PROD003"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a result like this:

```json
[
  {
    "product_id": "PROD003"
  }
]
```

Using the aggregation bellow:

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "products",
      "localField": "product_id",
      "foreignField": "product_id",
      "as": "products"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "products": {
        "$size": 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "product_id": 1
    }
  }
])
```